# Está dando erro de Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

Erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: logar is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Alguem pode me ajudar?

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/login.js" type="text/javascritp"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <form class="container">
                <div class="row login-form" style="margin: 0 auto;margin-top: 120px;"
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Coloque seu email">
                  <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca compartilharemos seu e-mail com mais ninguém.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Coloque sua senha">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Lembre-mim</label>
                </div>
              </form>
              <button onclick="logar()" style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function logar(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var senha = document.getElementById("senha");

    if(email == "admin@admin.com".com && senha.value == "admin"){
        localStorage.setItem("acesso", true);

        windows.location.href = "index.html";
    }else{
        alert("Usuario ou senha invaalidos!");
    }
}
```

Comment: esse código está estranho, deve dar erro no ".com" sozinho fora das aspas no if: `if(email == "admin@admin.com".com`

Comment: O `type` da tag `<script>` tá com erro de digitação. Não que esse seja o problema, mas é um problema

Answer (score 0):

Oi tudo bem acho que o **Html** não conseguiu detectar o seu arquivo externo **Javascript**

Por isso ele mostra que a *function* `logar()` não foi definida,  e também porque o código para identificar ao arquivo externo está escrito errado.

Errado:
`<script src="js/login.js" type="text/javascritp"></script>`

O certo é `<script src="js/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

só mudar como está escrito **Javascript**

Reparei também que como os amigos no comentário falaram o **.com** esta fora da área de string no **html**.